# undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass on datetime field

Tags: ruby, datetime, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view, I'm calling

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ...
  <%= post.published_on.to_date %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

"published_on" is a datetime field in my posts db:

```
#schema.rb
t.datetime "published_on"
```

And in my controller, I'm setting it using the 'now' method:

```
    def publish
      ...
      @post.published_on=DateTime.now
      ...
      end
    end
```

When the page loads, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
```

However, if I drop the 'to_date' method in the view, the page loads fine and the published_on field is populated with, for example, '2013-12-20 17:05:40 UTC'

My question is, why am I getting this error?  the 'to-date' method work?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated with question.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use `to_date` if `published_on` already returns a valid date format?  Perhaps you mean to use `strftime()`?

Comment: strftime() does the trick, thank you :)

Comment: Have you saved with `@post.save` your record after the updating the date time `@post.published_on=DateTime.now`

Comment: after the save procedure has completed, make sure that is it saved with `@post.changed?` that shell return `false`, and if it is read just after the save data field `p @post.published_on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Donovan.  The data was already in date format, what I was trying to do was format, and the appropriate way to do that was with `strftime()`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use

```
<%= @post.published_on.to_date %>
```

Note the use of the instance variable `@post` instead of a local variable `post`

Comment: Good eye, but that line is actually in a do loop on @post, which I've added to the question.  Thanks, though, really helpful for clarifying.